# Connection between sums and integrals over closed paths and their areas

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, differential-geometry, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Is there a deeper connection between the following identies involving sums or integrals over a closed path (resp. circle) resp. the area enclosed – e.g. a general principle that is underlying all of them?

1. Euler's totient is the [Fourier transform](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulersche_Phi-Funktion#Fourier-Transformation) of the greatest common divisor function:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \operatorname{gcd}(k,n)\cdot e^{i2\pi k/n} = \varphi(n)$$

2. The [sum of the $n$-th roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity#Summation) is $0$:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n e^{i2\pi k/n} = 0$$

3. [Cauchy's integral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem):

$$\oint_\gamma f(z)dz = 0 $$

4. [Cauchy's residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem):

$$\oint_{\gamma} f(z)dz = 2\pi i \sum_{k=1}^n\operatorname{I}(\gamma,a_k)\operatorname{Res}(f,a_k)$$

5. The [Gauss-Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem):

$$\int_{\partial M}k_g\ ds = \int_M K\ dA + 2\pi\chi(M)$$

For $K\equiv 0$:

$$\int_{\partial M}k_g\ ds = 2\pi\chi(M)$$

6. The [Chern–Gauss–Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem):

$$\int _{M}{\mbox{Pf}}(\Omega )=(2\pi )^{n}\chi (M)$$

Or is there possibly no deep connection between (all of) them, and the analogies are superficial?

Furthermore: Is this selection too arbitrary, and examples of such identities abound, actually?

---

A connection between 2, 3, 4 is demonstrated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081752/proof-without-words-of-oint-zdz-0-and-oint-dz-z-2-pi-i).

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the Stokes' theorem : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem . It links the integral on the boundary of a compact $\partial K$ of a differential form $\alpha$ to the integral of its differential $d\alpha$ on the compact. It is a kind of generalisation of the fact that the integral of a function on a segment is the difference at the boundary of the segment of a primitive. It is an essential formula which is behind almost all formula with integrals. (Green-Riemann, Green-Ostrogradski, integration by parts, Bochner's formula, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But what does it tell me about the connection with the sums?